# TypeError: descriptor 'transpose' requires a 'numpy.ndarray' object but received a 'Tensor'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow2.0

I have upgraded a Tensorflow 1.x code to Tensorflow 2.0, but I have some problems to fix. One of them is about numpy array vs tensor in some parts of the code. I don't know how to fix it.

I tried with `tf.transpose`, `tf.linalg.matrix_transpose`, `tf.linalg.transpose` in line 29, both in outside and inside function. Also I have added `.eval()` in the line 30 to get a np.array as you can see in this last attempt:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

~/Documents/example.py in <module>
    202                       soft_gumbel_softmax=False,
    203                       hard_gumbel_softmax=False,
--> 204                       batch_discriminator=False)
    205 
    206 # optimizer

~/Documents/models/gan.py in __init__(self, vertexes, edges, nodes, embedding_dim, decoder_units, discriminator_units, decoder, discriminator, soft_gumbel_softmax, hard_gumbel_softmax, batch_discriminator)
     33         with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('generator'):
     34             self.edges_logits, self.nodes_logits = self.decoder(self.embeddings, decoder_units, vertexes, edges, nodes,
---> 35                                                                 training=self.training, dropout_rate=self.dropout_rate)
     36 
     37         with tf.compat.v1.name_scope('outputs'):

~/Documents/models/__init__.py in decoder_adj(inputs, units, vertexes, edges, nodes, training, dropout_rate)
     28                                                   activation=None), (-1, edges, vertexes, vertexes))
     29         edges_logits = tf.transpose(a=(edges_logits + tf.linalg.matrix_transpose(edges_logits)) / 2, perm=(0, 2, 3, 1))
---> 30         edges_logits = tf.compat.v1.layers.dropout(edges_logits.eval(), dropout_rate, training=training)
     31 
     32     with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('nodes_logits'):

TypeError: descriptor 'transpose' requires a 'numpy.ndarray' object but received a 'Tensor'
```

These last lines are from this function:

```
def decoder_adj(inputs, units, vertexes, edges, nodes, training, dropout_rate=0.):
    output = multi_dense_layers(inputs, units, activation=tf.nn.tanh, dropout_rate=dropout_rate, training=training)

    with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('edges_logits'):
        edges_logits = tf.reshape(tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(inputs=output, units=edges * vertexes * vertexes,
                                                  activation=None), (-1, edges, vertexes, vertexes))
        edges_logits = tf.transpose(a=(edges_logits + np.matrix.transpose(edges_logits)) / 2, perm=(0, 2, 3, 1))
        edges_logits = tf.compat.v1.layers.dropout(edges_logits, dropout_rate, training=training)

    with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope('nodes_logits'):
        nodes_logits = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(inputs=output, units=vertexes * nodes, activation=None)
        nodes_logits = tf.reshape(nodes_logits, (-1, vertexes, nodes))
        nodes_logits = tf.compat.v1.layers.dropout(nodes_logits, dropout_rate, training=training)

    return edges_logits, nodes_logits
```

I would like to know where, in which format, why and how I should transform the inputs.

Comment: Can you post more of the the original code? But by looking at the error, `eval()` in line 30 seems to be a problem. You probably don't need it there.

Comment: `eval()` is the last try, hoping that it would return a numpy array to solve this problem. I have added the function from where the last lines belong.